# Using addVars in Gurobi to create variables with three indices

Tags: python, dictionary, variables, gurobi

I am pretty new to modeling with Gurobi/python interface. I want to create some z variables with two indices i, j. I have tried several methods but I get errors every time. I hope anyone gets in touch with me and discuss with me this piece of code to get the variables as I intend to.

'''
from gurobipy import GRB,quicksum,Model
m = Model ('DARP')

R = [i for i in range(1,6)] # Requests

Crn = {1: [12,13,14], 2: [15,16,17], 3: [18,19,20], 4: [21,22,23], 5:[24,25,26] }

for r in R:
    z = m.addVars(list(Crn[r]),list(Crn[r]),vtype=GRB.BINARY)

for r in R :
    MM= quicksum(z [i,j] for i in list(Crn[r]) for j in list(Crn[r]) if j!=i )
print (MM)
'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to do something like this:

```
import gurobipy as grb

m = grb.Model()
R = list(range(1,6)) # Requests
Crn = {1: [12,13,14], 2: [15,16,17], 3: [18,19,20], 4: [21,22,23], 5:[24,25,26] }

for r in R:
    # Adding variables
    z = m.addVars(list(Crn[r]),list(Crn[r]),vtype=grb.GRB.BINARY)
    m.update()

    # Constructing linear expression
    MM = grb.quicksum([z [i,j] for i in list(Crn[r]) for j in list(Crn[r]) if j!=i])
    print (MM)
```

Please, note that the Model instance must be updated after adding variables in order to use them.

Comment: Based on your code I get the next output , I would like to understand please
<gurobi.LinExpr: C1 + C2 + C3 + C5 + C6 + C7>
<gurobi.LinExpr: C10 + C11 + C12 + C14 + C15 + C16>
<gurobi.LinExpr: C19 + C20 + C21 + C23 + C24 + C25>
<gurobi.LinExpr: C28 + C29 + C30 + C32 + C33 + C34>
<gurobi.LinExpr: C37 + C38 + C39 + C41 + C42 + C43>

Comment: For each element in R, a [linear expression](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/py_lex2.html) is created, stored in MM, and printed. The argument name of the function addVars is None, so default names for variables are used by gurobi: C1, C2, etc. Please explain what is your main goal so I could be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your consideration. I have built a complete model for a vehicle routing problem, Dial-a-ride problem. I created random data by python. unfortunately, something is not going well in a specific part of the code. How can  I discuss more with you "+201027690618"